# Get combination and permutation of values from multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, node.js, multidimensional-array

```
var a = ['3','4','5'];
var b = [{"cluster_id":25,"element_ids":"3,4"},{"cluster_id":26,"element_ids":"4"},{"cluster_id":27,"element_ids":"3"},{"cluster_id":29,"element_ids":"5"},{"cluster_id":30,"element_ids":"4,5"},{"cluster_id":31,"element_ids":"3,5"},{"cluster_id":32,"element_ids":"3,4"},{"cluster_id":33,"element_ids":"3,4,5"}]
```

I want to find all combinations of `element_ids` arrays in `b` that have the same elements as the array `a` (currently set to `['3', '4', 5']`). The combinations should be specified using the `cluster_id` values associated with the combined `element_ids`. The combined `element_ids` need not be in the same order as they appear in `a`.

For example:

- `b[0]` has `cluster_id = 25` and `element_ids = ['3', '4']`
- `b[3]` has `cluster_id = 29` and `element_ids = ['5']`
- Combining the `element_ids` of `b[0]` and `b[3]` results in `['3', '4', '5']`
- As the combined `element_ids` arrays have the same elements as `a`, this is considered a match
- By this we would say that "25, 29" is a match

The expected matches for `b` above matching `a` would be:

- 26, 27, 29
- 25, 29
- 27, 30
- 31, 26
- 33

And how can we do this in nodejs?